# Who is right about inodes? df or tune2fs?

Tags: disk-usage, inode

On my Redhat 6.5, I get two different results on free inodes.

Using df :

```
[root@xxxx ~]# df -i /dev/mapper/data_vg-data_lv 
Filesystem                   Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on 
/dev/mapper/data_vg-data_lv 2555904 72422 2483482    3% /data/cfa000/x1/data
```

Using tune2fs :

```
[root@xxxx ~]# tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/data_vg-data_lv | grep -i inode 
...
Inode count:              2555904 
Free inodes:              846816 
...
```

Can this situation be normal? If not, what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you 100% sure, that results come from the same node? And if, is your server updated to the latest erratas?

Comment: I'm connected through ssh on this server so I'm sure. What do you mean by latest erratas please?

Answer (score 6):

df should be correct. tune2fs inode count is not checking the superblock kept in memory so it's unreliable for mounted volumes. If you unmount /dev/mapper/data_vg-data_lv and check with tune2fs it should show the same values as df -i

Comment: Ok I'm going to unmount it and test later on. However, I have another server which is the same as this one with same FS mounted and both df -i and tune2fs -l show the same value. Also, the difference inode count seems so big.

Comment: Are you using different filesystems on the two servers? As I understand it the ext4 superblock is only written to disk when unmounting, but it's possible different filesystems update sooner.

Comment: No, only ext4 on both servers. Monday I will be able to unmount the FS (I cannot stop the application before) and test.